# Determining CPU time required to execute loop

Tags: c++

I've done some SO searching and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808398/easily-measure-elapsed-time) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22872614/timing-a-for-loop-with-clock) outlining timing methods.

My problem is that I need to determine the CPU time (in milliseconds) required to execute the following loop:

```
for (int i = 0, temp = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        temp = (i / 2) + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = 2 * i;
    }
}
```

I've looked at two methods, `clock()` and `stead_clock::now()`. Per the [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/), I know that `clock()` returns "ticks" so I can get it in seconds by dividing the difference using `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`. The [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/steady_clock/) also mention that `steady_clock` is designed for interval timing, but you have to call `duration_cast<milliseconds>` to change its unit.

What I've done to time the two (since doing both in the same run may lead to one taking longer since the other was called first) is run them each by themselves:

```
clock_t t = clock();
for (int i = 0, temp = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        temp = (i / 2) + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = 2 * i;
    }
}
t = clock() - t;
cout << (float(t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC) * 1000 << "ms taken" << endl;

chrono::steady_clock::time_point p1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
for (int i = 0, temp = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        temp = (i / 2) + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = 2 * i;
    }
}
chrono::steady_clock::time_point p2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
cout << chrono::duration_cast<milliseconds>(p2-p1).count() << "ms taken" << endl;
```

Output:

```
0ms taken
0ms taken
```

Do both these methods floor the result? Surely some fractal of milliseconds took place?

So which is ideal (or rather, more appropriate) for determining the CPU time required to execute the loop? At first glance, I would argue for `clock()` since the docs specifically tell me that its for determining CPU time.

For context, my `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` holds a value of `1000`.

**Edit/Update:**

Tried the following:

```
clock_t t = clock();
for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
    volatile int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            temp = (i / 2) + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = 2 * i;
        }
    }
}
t = clock() - t;
cout << (float(t) * 1000.0f / CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000000.0f) << "ms taken" << endl;
```

Outputs: 0.019953ms taken

```
clock_t start = clock();
volatile int temp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        temp = (i / 2) + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = 2 * i;
    }
}
clock_t end = clock();
cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << 1000.0 * (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "ms taken" << endl;
```

Outputs: 0.00ms taken

```
chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point p1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
volatile int temp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        temp = (i / 2) + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = 2 * i;
    }
}
chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point p2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
cout << (chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(p2 - p1).count()) / 1000.0 << "ms taken" << endl;
```

Outputs: 0.072ms taken

```
chrono::steady_clock::time_point p1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
volatile int temp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        temp = (i / 2) + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = 2 * i;
    }
}
chrono::steady_clock::time_point p2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
cout << (chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(p2 - p1).count()) / 1000.0f << "ms taken" << endl;
```

Outputs: 0.044ms

So the question becomes, which is valid? The second method to me seems invalid because I think the loop is completing faster than a millisecond.

I understand the first method (simply to execute longer) but the last two methods produce drastically different results.

One thing I've noticed is that after compiling the program, the first time I run it I may get 0.073ms (for the `high_resolution_clock`) and 0.044ms (for the `steady_clock`) at first, but all subsequent runs are within the range of 0.019 - 0.025ms.

Comment: Aside: since this code is silly/pointless (it keeps overwriting the value of `temp`, which eventually is thrown away), the compiler might choose to eliminate all or part of its output. Anyway, 10.000 iterations isn't very much for such a simple piece of code - try upping the loop count by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: Why do you think that it takes any time to do nothing? Your loops have no effect on the observable behaviour of your program

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Did that and they do in fact produce results. I had the same thought, but these are my constraints. Please see my response to Caleth.

Comment: @Caleth The time it takes to execute this loop is later assigned as a metric of 1 UT later in the program for objects. So I need to get `1 UT = x ms` where `x` is that unknown time in milliseconds to run that loop.

Comment: Even if the compiler doesn't optimize everything out, `0ms` might be the correct result. For example `2 * i` is the same as `i + i` which takes a fraction of a nanosecond on a PC.

Comment: Note that you are doing integer arithmetic on (apparently millisecond) values when you `clock() - t`, so if the *count of milliseconds* hasn't gone up, 0ms **is** the correct result

Comment: Check this [Google benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark)

Comment: @VictorGubin Looking to implement without 3rd party packages, thanks though

Answer (score 2):

You can do the loop a million times, and divide. You can also add the volatile keyword to avoid some compiler optimizations.

```
clock_t t = clock();
for (int j = 0, j < 1000000; j++) {
    volatile int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            temp = (i / 2) + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = 2 * i;
        }
    }
}
t = clock() - t;
cout << (float(t) * 1000.0f / CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000000.0f) << "ms taken" << endl;
```

Comment: At this point my question changes to: Is there any difference between using your method over a `chrono::high_resolution_clock` to measure this? I like that yours uses the `clock()` which specifically measures CPU time, and the other method actually measures wall time. Other than that the differences (output wise) are marginal at best.

Comment: Also, turns out that on Windows [clock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/4e2ess30(v=vs.110)) measures wall time which would explain near identical times for it and `chrono::high_resolution_clock`. So I suppose what would be the portable variant across Windows and Linux?

Comment: Interesting comment about windows, I didn't know that. The std clock is defined to return the CPU time used by the process, and can differ from the wall time, so that would be the most correct (but not so on windows then). The chrono gives the walltime, so that can turn out to be longer than the actual running time you want to know. You can maybe get more accurate results by increasing your thread/process priority, but it's no guarantee the CPU will not be used for another process.

Comment: So, in conclusion, if you want to have an "execution time unit", I would go for the walltime, and take the average over multiple loops and multiple runs.

Answer (score 0):

Well using GetTickCount() seems to be solution, I hope

```
double start_s = GetTickCount();
for (int i = 0, temp = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        temp = (i / 2) + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = 2 * i;
    }
}
double stop_s = GetTickCount();
cout << (stop_s - start_s) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC) * 1000 << "ms taken" << endl;
```

For me returns between 16-31ms

Comment: that's mainly down to the precision of `GetTickCount`